# Aus and NZ tourist visa for Indian Passport holder residing in Germany

Tags: indian-citizens, australia, tourist-visas, new-zealand, german-residents

I'm a EU blue card holder for more than a year living in Germany.

I'm getting married in end of March 2020 in Chennai, India and we want to go on a honeymoon to both countries Aus and NZ in first week of April.

I want to apply for tourist visa ONLY for me (my fiancee would apply from Chennai) for both countries from here in Germany.

- Is this possible?
- Has someone else done this?
- If yes, could you please guide me find the right information.

Comment: Visiting both countries in only one week will be hectic, my advice is not to combine them unless you have three weeks at least.

Answer (score 2):

Neither country requires visa applicants to apply from their country of citizenship, so you can apply from Germany.

You can apply online for both countries.  Fill out the online application form, and scan and upload supporting documents.  For Australia, the process is entirely electronic as applications from Germany are (as of time of writing) not required to [provide biometrics](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/meeting-our-requirements/biometrics).  For New Zealand, you may be asked to send your passport for verification.

For further information, please see:

- Australia: [Visitor (subclass 600) visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600/tourist-stream-overseas#HowTo)
- New Zealand: [Visitor visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/process-fees/visitor-visa?nationality=nationality-IND&country=residence-DEU&applying=no&submethod=Applying+on+online+form&selection=&qs=1)

Comment: It might be a good idea for them to make both applications from the same account. Both Australia and NZ allow this.

Comment: @jcm:Thanks a lot,for your suggestion.Can you please help me the "same account". Is it ImmiAccount you are talking about?

Comment: @VigneshRajendran You can lodge applications for both yourself and your wife using the same ImmiAccount (Australia) and RealMe account (NZ).

Comment: @VigneshRajendran yep, what k2moo4 said.

Comment: @k2moo4 Thanks  a lot for your answers